# strange compiler error with C# mono

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, mono

I have this code :

```
int? sum=Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Sum((i) =>
        {
            if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0))
                return i;
            return null;
        });
```

This code doesn't compile, it generates this error :

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I changed the code to this :

```
int? sum=Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Sum<int>((int i) =>
        {
            if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0))
                return i;
            return null;
        });
```

But the compiler error remains.

I don't understand , `Enumerable.Range` returns a collection of integers and it's obvious I want the `Sum` that returns int? , otherwise `i` should be `decimal` and as I said it doesn't matter if I insert `int` before `i` or not.

When I make `sum` a `decimal?` variable it compiles.

I thought it might be a mono bug, I don't see anything like that in [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?component=C%23&product=Compilers&resolution=---) bug list.

So Am I missing something or should I file a bug ?

My mono version is 4.4.1, my OS is Arch linux x64.

Comment: From : (int i) To : (int) i

Comment: @jdweng I don't understand you

Comment: Then, make a bug report to mono : http://www.mono-project.com/community/bugs/ in dotnetfiddle, your code has no error.

Comment: @x... thanks, I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stripped down test program that demonstrates the problem outside of the BCL:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
static class Program {
  static void Test1(Func<int?> f)     { WriteLine("Test1(Func<int?>)");     }
  static void Test1(Func<decimal?> f) { WriteLine("Test1(Func<decimal?>)"); }
  static void Test2(Func<decimal?> f) { WriteLine("Test2(Func<decimal?>)"); }
  static void Test2(Func<int?> f)     { WriteLine("Test2(Func<int?>)");     }
  static void Main() {
    Test1(() => null);
    Test2(() => null);
  }
}
```

When compiled with Mono (4.4), this prints:

```
Test1(Func<decimal?>)
Test2(Func<int?>)
```

When compiled with Roslyn, this prints:

```
Test1(Func<int?>)
Test2(Func<int?>)
```

When going through the C# 5.0 language specification, ultimately, which overload should be picked comes down to *7.5.3.3 Better conversion from expression*, but it doesn't address this case. It gives some specific scenarios in which one overload is better than another, but for it to work here, it would need to act on what it calls the *inferred return type*. However, `null` does not have a type. There is no inferred return type. That leaves us with nothing in the language specification that describes which overload to use.

**The 5.0 language specification says the call is ambiguous. Compilers should generate an error.**

Unfortunately, the language specification does not describe Microsoft's compiler. This has forced Mono to implement ugly hacks that attempt to mimic Microsoft's behaviour, because refusing to compile code that does compile with Microsoft's compiler is an easy way to get people not to take Mono seriously, as you've seen in the response to this question. Those ugly hacks are not perfect and probably never will be unless the specification correctly describes the language they designed.

An unofficial C# 6.0 language specification has been made public at https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/README.md. It describes some tweaks to the overload resolution rules (look for 7.5.3.3 Better conversion from expression and 7.5.3.5 Better conversion target):

- `int?` is a better conversion target than `decimal?`, since there is an implicit conversion from `int?` to `decimal?`, but not vice versa.
- therefore, `Func<int?>` is a better conversion target than `Func<decimal?>`.
- therefore, a conversion from `() => null` to `Func<int?>` is better than  `Func<decimal?>`.

**The 6.0 language specification will probably say the code is valid, and Roslyn is right. But that language specification has not been finalised yet.**

Since the C# 6.0 language specification hasn't been finalised yet, it's difficult for Mono to implement it accurately and it appears that it hasn't been done yet.

Whether you treat it as a workaround of a Mono bug or missing feature, or as a fix of your code to make it more compatible to C# 5.0 though, the result is the same: using `default(int?)` instead of `null`, as suggested by Steve too, will make it work. In C# 5.0, the way it works is by giving the anonymous function an inferred return type of `int?`, resolving the ambiguity in the desired overload's favour.

Comment: "the language specification does not describe Microsoft's compiler" so I would obtain the same compiler error If I used visual studio 2013 (or more specifically the legacy compiler, that is not Roslyn) ?

Comment: @niceman I'm fairly sure the legacy compiler and the C# 5.0 specification do not match up, that it was already working the way you expect even before the spec allowed it. Will do a quick check when I can.

Comment: @niceman With the csc.exe supplied with .NET Framework, which does not implement C# 6.0 and complains about my `using static`, after changing that, the code in my answer here is flagged as ambiguous. However, if I change the `() => null` to `() => { return 0; return null; }` similarly to what you have, which should be equally ambiguous according to the C# 5.0 specification, it accepts it and picks the `Func<int?>` overload just like Roslyn does. So the old compiler did not match either the old spec or the new spec... I'm happy to see that it has been improved since.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a bug, as this does not happen with the compiler shipped with VisualStudio.

A work-around for mono seems to be to return `default(int?)` instead of null.

```
int? sum=Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Sum((i) =>
    {
        if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0))
            return i;
        return default(int?);
    });
```

Comment: "Definitely a bug, as this does not happen with the compiler shipped with VisualStudio." -- C# is supposed to be defined by a language specification. That language specification leaves some things unspecified. If it does, then the bug is in the code for relying on that unspecified behaviour. While I do suspect the language specification does define the behaviour, and defines it the same way VS treats it, an answer should really show where the language spec (or MS documentation) defines which `Sum` overload should be called